# Edit android resource file *.arsc

Tags: android

Is it possible to decompile, edit and recompile an android resource file (*.arsc)? There was a tool like `ResEdit` for standard `res` files... but It doesn't work for `arsc`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that unless you have that particular OEM's source and change the res folder or the overlays folder.
You can at least view the files inside it using Android studio itself. 
Use "Analyze Apk..." option under "Build" menu and select the particular apk which the *.arsc is part of.